# Simple sequential std::iota faster than the parallel equivalent

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, vectorization, tbb

I have a vector of 1 billion `int`s.
I want to initialize with the numbers 0 to 1 billion.

- STL's `std::iota`

(time: **0.63** s):

```cpp
std::iota(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0);
```

- To make it parallel we can use `std::for_each` with `par` policy:

time: **0.68** s (8% slower than sequentail iota)

```cpp
std::for_each(std::execution::par, v.begin(), v.end(), [&v](int& x) { x = (&x - data(v)); });
```

- Now trying possible vectorization with `std::for_each` and `unseq` policy:

time: **0.63** s (same as sequential iota)

```cpp
std::for_each(std::execution::unseq, v.begin(), v.end(), [&v](int& x) { x = (&x - data(v)); });
```

- TBB's `parallel_loop`

time: **0.68** s (8% slower than sequential iota)

```cpp
tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, N),
  [&](tbb::blocked_range<int>& r) {
    for (int i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); ++i)
      v[i] = i;
  });
```

---

The compiler is **not** generating any fancy vectorization for the case of `std::iota`, just a simple sequential loop. You can check it here: https://godbolt.org/z/Px57dPz3e

---

CPU: **24 cores** (2 x **Xeon E5-2620 (each 6 HT cores)**)

Compiler: **gcc 10.2.0** (FreeBSD Ports Collection)

Compile options: **-O2 -fopenmp -fopenmp-simd -ltbb**

---

So my question is why can't parallelization (with 24 cores) help? I can see that all 24 cores are at 100% when running the parallel versions)

Comment: Parallelization would help if CPU is the bottleneck. If not it may not help or make it worse, which quite possible is the case here. But it is not clear what is your question.

Comment: Bottlenecking on memory bus speed,

Comment: I expect the bottleneck is not CPU performance since it takes less than 1 clock tick to add 1 to a number. Instead the bottleneck is the RAM performance.

Comment: What are the error margins on your measured times? Did you also do warm-up runs before starting the measurement? Did you eliminate biases as much as possible? If you are not already using a benchmark framework that takes care of the many issues you need to deal with, I suggest you find one, for example [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark).

Comment: What if you manually split the work up assigning each core to fill out one section (like with 2 cores you'd split it so the first fills out the first half and the second does the other)? Does std::for_each do this behind the scenes?

Comment: Unless each core has separate memory allocated to it, all cores will need to share the data bus and the address bus between the Core and Memory.  Your bottleneck is probably the data and address bus usage (think of a thousand cars all having to go through an intersection, one car at a time).

Comment: This is dual processor 6 core CPU + HT from 2012. I expect there is separate memory (up to quad channel) attached to each 6C / 12T CPU however all cores could share the ram from 1 of the CPUs depending on how the system is configured. OEMs don't always configure for performance or better said the base model may be poorly configured in order to force the user to pay a premium for a well configured memory setup.

Comment: Tbb’s blocked range defaults to one item per block. It’s supposed to be over 10k instructions per block to get good performance. Try adding `1<<15` as a third argument to `tbb::blocked_range`. Also, if you at profiling it may be that the thread pool needs to get set up on first use.

Comment: Your `for_each()` is very poorly written, confusing the compiler so it fails to vectorize this *obviously vectorizable problem*. gcc will happily  [vectorize](https://godbolt.org/z/8P77h3daz) sane code.

Comment: @EOF In your code `c` is a shared mutable and has race condition under `unseq` policy. Even in that case it will be slower than my implementation (around 0.64s).

Comment: @Ben I tried with 1<<15, but still the same timing.

Comment: @G. Sliepen Unfortunately due to a bug in TBB on FreeBSD I can't use Google-Benchmark, but the timings are very stable. variations are sub milisecond.

Comment: @drescherjm and Thomas Matthews This system has two memory banks (1 per cpu socket), and 12 channels each. But currently has just one 16G module installed. I should fix that! I think the actual issue as you and Richard Critten and Slava said, the bottleneck is the CPU. I am will try with a better memory config.

Comment: oopse correction: bottleneck is the memory bus